# Help me understand my linear algebra book

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $(v_1,...,v_m)$ is a list of vectors in $V$, then each $v_j$ is a linear com- bination of $(v_1,...,v_m)$ (to show this, set $a_j = 1$ and let the other a’s in $a_1v_1 +···+a_mv_m$ equal 0.Thus span$(v_1,...,v_m)$ contains each $v_j$.

What does  this mean? Does this mean any vector can be written as a linear combination of the rest of  the vectors? But how ?

> to show this, set $a_j = 1$ and let the other a’s in $a_1v_1 +···+a_mv_m$ equal 0

^^^ How is this a proof? I don't understand.

---

> Conversely, because subspaces are closed under scalar multiplication and addition, every subspace of V containing each vj must contain span $(v_1 , . . . , v_m )$. Thus the span of a list of vectors in V is the smallest subspace of V containing all the vectors in the list.

Neither do I understand what is happening here. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}\\v_1$ is a linear combination of $\{\\v_1,\\v_2,\ldots,\\v_m\}$" means that it is possible to fill in scalars so that the equation
$$\\v_1=(\cdots)\\v_1+(\cdots)\\v_2+\cdots+(\cdots)\\v_m$$
is true.  Can you find suitable scalars?

For the second bit, try first to understand the case $m=2$.  If $\\v_1,\\v_2$ are in $V$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are scalars, then

- $\lambda_1\\v_1$ is in $V$ since $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication;
- $\lambda_2\\v_2$ is in $V$ since $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication;
- $\lambda_1\\v_1+\lambda_2\\v_2$ is in $V$ since $V$ is closed under addition.

So $V$ contains every linear combination of $\\v_1,\\v_2$, that is, $V$ contains ${\rm span}(\\v_1,\\v_2)$.

Comment: David I understood. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, the book essentially says
$$0\cdot v_1+\cdots +0\cdot v_{j-1}+ 1\cdot v_j +0\cdot v_{j+1}+\cdots
+0\cdot v_m =v_j. $$

Second part: $S=Span(v_1,\cdots,v_m)$ is smallest vector space containing all $v_1,\cdots,v_m$, since $S$ is contained in every vector space $X$ containing
$v_1,\cdots,v_m$. This because any such vector space $X$ containing $v_1,\cdots,v_m$ contains all vectors of the form $\{\sum a_j v_j\}$, which is by definition $Span(v_1,\cdots,v_m)$.

Comment: Milly! Thank you very much. I understood the first part very clearly. The second part, what is "Vector Space X"?

Comment: a vector space which I name "$X$" (just a name, the important part is if $v\in X$, then $av\in X$ for any scalar $a$, and if $v,u\in X$, then $v+u\in X$).

Comment: Milly I understood. Thank you very much